# How is melee combat experience calculated in Morrowind?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

In The Elder Scrolls III: Morrowind, I am having difficulty selecting a weapon to use. I have several with higher base damage and not-so-useful enchantments, and several with lower base damage and very effective enchantments. I want to use one which is enchanted with Fire Damage and has lower base damage, but I still want to efficiently gain Blunt Weapon levels.

Would leveling up be slowed down by using a weapon with lower base damage?

Is damage from enchantments accounted for in experience in the appropriate weapon skill, or is experience calculated in a different way entirely (per successful hit)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [UESP Wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Blunt_Weapon), weapon skills are trained regardless of damage inflicted. Each successful hit yields 1.0 EXP Points